# Index UITableview sections by numbers

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm using a `UITableView` with sections to build index table, lets say that i have an Array with 500 of string data. Now i need to index the table for an easy scroll  by 1 , 50 , 100 , 150 , 200 and so on until 500. so when i scroll to 50 i go to indexPath.row 50.

i really couldn't achieve it and i tried the following :

```
@IBOutlet weak var mytableView: UITableView!

var tableData = [String]()
var indexOfNumbers = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


    tableData = [

    // 500 lines of string array of different starting letter

    ]

    let indexNumbers = "0 50 100 150 200 250 300 350 400 450 500"
    indexOfNumbers = indexNumbers.componentsSeparatedByString(" ")


}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return tableData.count
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) 

    // Configure the cell...
    cell.textLabel?.text = tableData[indexPath.section]

    return cell
}



func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}


func sectionIndexTitlesForTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> [String]? {

    return indexOfNumbers
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, sectionForSectionIndexTitle title: String, atIndex index: Int) -> Int {
    let temp = indexOfNumbers as NSArray
    return temp.indexOfObject(title)
}
```

Comment: well as i am seeing you have 11 section with 1 row each. You can scroll to each row (as per your code only row of the section). If you want to do what you explained in your question, separate  `tableData` in 50-50 cells (in array of array manner). load 50 cells in each section. remove last section (the 500th).

Comment: okey i see, @HarvantS. then i have to try it ! i will get back !

Comment: @HarvantS. i thought about separating the array if i used for loop many times that will be a lot of calculation for the app ? any other ways to ?

Comment: If you want such system, you have to separate the array. Here i can help with this question. If you want to know something else please post another question. Firstly try to sort out what you asked.

Comment: BTW here is your second question's answer https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/subarrayWithRange:

Comment: i will look for it, just fixing one by one !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91243/discussion-between-harvant-s-and-aaoii).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As i am seeing you have 11 section with 1 row each. You can scroll to each row (as per your code the only row of the section). If you want to do what you explained in your question, separate `tableData` in 50-50 cells (in array of array manner). Load 50 cells in each section, remove last section (the 500th).

You need to fix this too because `componentsSeparatedByString` returns an array of separated components.

```
var indexOfNumbers = [NSArray]() 
let indexes = "0 50 100 150 200 250 300 350 400 450 500" 
indexOfNumbers = indexes.componentsSeparatedByString(" ")
```

Your can separate your array by `subarrayWithRange` method of `NSArray` class. **Code in objective C.**

```
NSMutableArray *mutA=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
{
    NSArray *halfArray;
    NSRange theRange;

    theRange.location = i*50;
    theRange.length = [mapCat count] / 10;

    halfArray = [mapCat subarrayWithRange:theRange];
    [mutA addObject:halfArray];
}
```